# Getting error saying "missing script: start" while using "docker compose up" but i have set up "start" on package.json

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

[image: ERROR on the termminal]

I was trying to containerize the node and mongo app while I encountered the error the docker file[image: Image of Docker file] is written as in the second image.
Image of docker compose file.[image: Image of docker-composefile]
Please suggest any solution

The GITHUB link of repo - https://github.com/siddharth-codes/productdb

Answer (score 1):

### i suggest to annotate this line:

`COPY package*.json .`

and the dockerfile should be like:

```
FROM node:alpine
WORKDIR /usr/src/app 
#initializee the workdir in host system linux

COPY . .
#npm ci will install all the dependencies of the required version
RUN npm ci
#copy files from our project folder..
CMD ["npm", "start"]
#above line is  ame as npm startnp
```

Also, i ran `docker-compose up -d`  and it worked fine on my server.

Comment: But the container get disposed ,you can check it using docker ps . Try using "docker  compose up" without detach mode.if u get any solution please suggest it

Comment: @Siddharthj i think you should open a new terminal,and use `docker ps| grep container` to check if the container is exists.